# C# Web Api - Salesforce - How to get auth code via an api call, not via browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, salesforce

We got a client_id from Salesforce and the url. But the output of this is an HTML page where we need to click and enter our credentials to get the auth code. But ours is an API call and we dont want the user to enter the credentials via browser. How can I do this in C# web api.

This is the url we hit from api.

> https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=YYY&response_type=code

What I am looking here is that how to get a json response with auth code, rather than an HTML page where we need to enter our credentials. In fact I don't even need a redirect url, just the code is needed.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com is probably your best bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a headless integration into Salesforce, you should use the JWT OAuth flow, rather than the Web Server flow. JWT authentication can be completed entirely without user interaction.

This flow is documented for the Salesforce platform in [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow for Server-to-Server Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5).